# SQL Statement for gouping messages

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following code and I'm trying to group the messages

Here is a picture of database table and how the groups should be

[image]

and here is the SQL statement

```
SELECT a.* FROM `user_messages` `a` 
JOIN (
    SELECT `sender`, MAX(`id`) `last_id` FROM `user_messages` WHERE `receiver` = '1' GROUP BY `sender`
) `b` 
ON `a`.`sender` = `b`.`sender` AND `a`.`id` = `b`.`last_id` 
WHERE `a`.`receiver` = '1'
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

OUTPUT:
[image]

I want to get somehow the last record where "receiver" is not my id, but "sender" is and name receiver column as "id" or something.
...so what i want is following result:

```
id    |   msg
13852      123
48         Hello!
17         321
```

Here is a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e06d57/3/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To map my generic answer to your particular use case (using example 1):

```
SELECT receiver AS id, msg
FROM user_messages outerTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  ( SELECT * 
    FROM user_messages innerTable
    WHERE innerTable.sender = outerTable.sender
      AND innerTable.receiver = outerTable.receiver
      AND innerTable.added > outerTable.added
  )
  AND sender = 1
```

Comment: yeeep it works! you rock! thank you very much @memimomu

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common use case. There are several ways to write this code. Depending on the SQL engine used, they will be of different speeds.

I will use fairly generic column names. Tweak as needed.

```
SELECT common_id, msg
FROM myTable outerTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  ( SELECT * 
    FROM myTable innerTable
    WHERE innerTable.common_id = outerTable.common_id
      AND innerTable.time > outerTable.time
  )
```

Please note that if there are two rows with identical `common_id` and `time` columns, then both will show up in the output. You can replace the `>` with `>=` to hide both of those rows.

The other common approach is kind of difficult to make sense of, but here goes. Notice the similarities to the `NOT EXISTS` approach.

```
SELECT outerTable.common_id, outerTable.msg
FROM myTable outerTable
LEFT JOIN myTable innerTable
  ON  innerTable.common_id = outerTable.common_id
  AND innerTable.time > outerTable.time
WHERE innerTable.common_id IS NULL
```

Comment: hmmm.. it won't work... and how common_id will be generated?
ps. it's for MySQL

Comment: can you help me with an example?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you seem to want something like this:

```
select um.receiver as id, um.msg
from user_messages um
where um.sender = 1 and
      um.id = (select max(um2.id)
               from user_messages um2
               where um2.msg = um.msg and um2.receiver <> 1 and um.sender = 1
              );
```

It doesn't produce the desired output, but that is because the output is inconsistent with the text description.